# Unable to query as an INT from database using Python Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using python flask and have a database A that I am pulling the year from. I have defined the column in the database as an integer, but I am struggling to get my query to return integers. Right now, I am trying to find the max year in my query, so I can eventually add subsequent years.

```
def add():
    years = db.session.query(A.year.distinct().label("year"))
    maxyear = max(db.session.query(A.year.distinct().label("year")))
    return render_template("x.html",maxyear=maxyear,years=years,type=type(maxyear))
```

This function currently returns it as (maxyear , type):

```
 (2017,) , <class 'sqlalchemy.util._collections.result'>
```

I tried to do:

```
maxyear = int(max(db.session.query(A.year.distinct().label("year"))))
```

but received this error:

```
typeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object, or a number, not 'result'.
```

Any suggestions as to how I should adjust my query to correct this issue?

Comment: you get a collection as return - not a single value.  use a [0] to get the first one?

Comment: this worked! thank you! I can marked this as answered/closed if you add this comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you get a collection as return - not a single value. use a [0] to get the first one? – Patrick Artner

year = maxyear[0]

Comment: you can mark this as "self-answer" in about 48h :) I think you even get a badge for it.